# How to put a website online

Tags: wamp

As i have installed WAMP developer Pro recently and i have solved everything that it needed but the main problem is coming which is most important , i am unable to put my website online as i have made a url from WAMP developer and i have putted my all website file in it it is working fine in my as i type www.radharamnji.com it comes but other can not see it so please tell me how i can make it online so everyone can see it.

here is a pic of WAMP developer

[image]

Comment: Is your website in your local machine? If this is the case, you need a static IP address or a dynamic DNS to constantly check your IP. If you cannot set these up, your best option is a webhost to host your website for you.

Answer (score 0):

If You Have A Website and domain You Have To Upload All Of Your Files To Host Public_html Folder.
If You Want to change your computer to a server you have to buy a valid IP and set dns settings and ...
If You Upload Your Files On The Internet YOu Have Too Change Your Adrress to Relative.
For Example Change The Adrress Of Picture From (http:/localhost/img/img1.jpg) To (img/img1.jpg).

Comment: i do not want it forever i want it till my computer run or we can say for a little tile

Comment: Ask Your Question Clearly! You Have Hosting Or Not?

Answer (score 0):

The WAMP you are using has a guide for this located on its site's /howto section: "**Enabling Online and Internet Access of Websites...**".

Chances are:

1. Your Windows Firewall (and also anti-virus s/w such as McAfee) are blocking incoming port 80 and 443 TCP connections, and the httpd.exe process.
2. Your Router does not have any port-forwarding set up for WAN:80 to LAN:80.